# Run binary automatically as root

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I have root access.

How can I let a general user with little permissions run a binary file as root without a password?

I tried giving it root:wheel with chown, but that did not let a general user do what I wanted.

Comment: Making a binary run as root when it was not specifically designed to run as root can open *huge* security holes. For example, if it has some kind of file viewer that lets you specify your own pager, you can specify `bash` as your pager, and boom, you've got a root shell. If it lets you write to the file of your choice, you can specify `/etc/group` and add yourself to the root group.

Answer (score 1):

`chown` changes the owner, it doesn't make the binary run as the file owner. `chmod u+s` will do that however. `chmod g+s` will make the binary run with the file group permission on some systems as well (you don't mention what system you're running). These flags have very different effects on other files and especially folders. You should take a good long look at `man chmod` and `man chown` before diving in.

Also you should strongly consider using `sudo` instead of making the binary suid. When a binary is suid, anyone who can access the binary can run it as the file's owner. If you accidentally give a normal user write permissions to the binary, then they could replace it with anything that want and run it as root. `sudo` solves these security problems at the cost of requiring the user to prepend `sudo` to commands they want to run as root. You also have to setup the sodoers file with approproiate permissions.

Comment: in other words, `visudo` there is a few examples in there as well

Answer (score 0):

Run :-`visudo` (To edit the config file):-

Then edit the config file i.e sudoers file:-
`USERNAME ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/binaryfile`.

Save the file then you can run the binary file without requiring any password by running:-

`sudo "command to run binary file`".